# Use Jakarta-Faces in Tomcat 10.1

Tags: tomcat, jsf

I am trying to run a Jakarta EE 10 Web-app in Tomcat 10.1.13, using the Jakarta Server Faces, but I've run into this problem:

```
SEVERE: Servlet.init() for servlet [Faces Servlet] threw exception
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/faces/util/Util
at jakarta.faces.CurrentThreadToServletContext.getFactoryFinder(CurrentThreadToServletContext.java:51)
at jakarta.faces.FactoryFinder.getFactory(FactoryFinder.java:259)
at jakarta.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.acquireFacesContextFactory(FacesServlet.java:493)
at jakarta.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.init(FacesServlet.java:342)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:944)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:901)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:649)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:115)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:90)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:482)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:115)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:93)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:673)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:341)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:391)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:63)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:894)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1740)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.faces.util.Util
... 24 more
```

I've seen similar problems here in SO, but the best solution I could find was to add to pom.xml;

```
<dependency>
<groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
<artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
<version>2.2.20</version>
</dependency>
```

But the problem is that I am using Jakarta Server Faces 4.0, and not Java Server Faces 2.2. Other answers in similar questions were to add server-specific dependencies that handle that, so I looked up in Tomcat website, but found nothing clear about JSF.

What configuration do I need to have to run Jakarta Faces in Tomcat 10.1.13?

pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>------</groupId>
<artifactId>-----</artifactId>
<version>-----</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<name>-----</name>

<properties>
    <maven.compiler.release>17</maven.compiler.release>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
        <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
        <version>13.0.0</version>
        <classifier>jakarta</classifier>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jakarta.platform</groupId>
        <artifactId>jakarta.jakartaee-web-api</artifactId>
        <version>10.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.tomcat/tomcat -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat</artifactId>
        <version>10.1.13</version>
        <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<build>
    <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.11.0</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.4.0</version>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```